# Loading a python script source by filename for testing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I would like to create a test for a python 3.7+ **script** called `foo-bar` (that's the file name, and it has no `.py` extension):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

def foo(bar):
  return bar + 42

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(foo(1))
```

How can I load this file by path alone, so that I can test the `foo()` method?  The test should NOT trigger the `if main` condition.

**UPDATE** note that this is not about `executing` the file from the test (i.e. `exec('foo-bar')`), but rather loading/importing it as a module/resource, allowing the test code to execute `foo()` on it.

Comment: Why do you want to have a Python file without the `.py` extension?

Comment: 1) this code already exists, so backwards compat 2) this is a utility, like any other command - its language is an implementation detail that should not be exposed to the user of the utility (you don't care if your `ls` is written in c or go, right?  Could be done with a symlink, but that creates two files instead of one - over-complicating.

Comment: It it is a `.py` file, you can import it. If it is not, you cannot.

Comment: @DYZ this is NOT a dup - I am not executing the code, I need to `load` it. I think you are incorrect in marking it as a dup (and yes, I saw that post before posting this one)

Comment: If you mean you want to _read_ the file, then open it and read it. It is a text file, after all. There is no such thing as _loading_ a file.

Comment: no, of course not :)   By loading I mean loading it as a resource/code, i.e. possibly using `SourceFileLoader` -- allowing me to use reflection-like functionality (in .NET parlance) - thus making it possible to call the `foo()` method from the tests.

Comment: That's importing, and the dup has an answer for it.

Comment: @filbranden thx, but the `importlib.util.spec_from_file_location` keeps returning `None` for my usecase because the file has no `.py` extension.   @DYZ could you specify which answer you mean? I have looked at all of them, and runpy method is the closest, while still being a "run" rather than "import"

Comment: @filbranden please vote to reopen (gray link right under the post). Thx!

Comment: Yes I'm having the same trouble with `importlib.util`... This works for me: `foo_bar = imp.load_module('foo_bar', f, 'foo-bar', ('', 'r', imp.PY_SOURCE))`, passing it a file object for the 'foo-bar' file as `f`, but the `imp` module is deprecated and suggests `importlib.util` instead...

Comment: @filbranden this is awesome!  I was able to figure it out thanks to your answer -- `from importlib._bootstrap_external import SourceFileLoader` and `SourceFileLoader('foo-bar', path='.../foo-bar').load_module().foo(42)` !!!  I just hope an expert could comment on a better way to access `SourceFileLoader` rather than the import i used.

Comment: @filbranden could you post it as an answer and I will accept? thx for all your help!

Comment: @Yurik Posted an answer! Thanks for the great question! I'm glad we managed to keep it open as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the functions in [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) to load this module directly from the script file, without a `.py` extension.

To make this work, you need to use a loader explicitly, in this case [SourceFileLoader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader) will work.

```
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader

foo_bar = SourceFileLoader('foo_bar', './foo-bar').load_module()
```

At this point, you can use the functions from inside the module:

```
result = foo_bar.foo(1)
assert result == 43
```

Comment: thank you for helping figure it out!  One thing you may want to edit though -- it seems `foo_bar = SourceFileLoader('foo-bar', './foo-bar').load_module()` works just as well, without all the spec stuff, and it lets me call `foo_bar.foo(5)` directly.

Comment: @Yurik That's so much simpler! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I think, what you can do is temporarily create copy of the file with extension. py and after importing delete it

Comment: this would not be a good solution for a testing framework.  See above comments - hopefully @ filbranden will post an answer, or I will self-answer in a day.